# ACF Display Taxonomy Image Field

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have tried the following but it does not seem to display the image in taxonomy.

```
<?php if(get_field('my_image', 'album_category') ): ?>

    <img src="<?php the_field('my_image','album_category'); ?>"  />

<?php endif; ?>
```

and

```
$ac_image= get_field('my_image', 'album_category');

echo '<img src="' .$ac_image. '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to find the term id before displaying the field

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'album_category');
```

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/